# Google Chart API - is it possible to download the .js and work on it offline?

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to use the Google Chart API in one of my project.

Is it possible to download ONE JavaScript for it so that I can work offline?

I tried to download the script referred from the html page (jsapi)
and its code seems to load up other scripts:

```
google.loader.ServiceBase = 'https://www.google.com/uds';
google.loader.GoogleApisBase = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax';
...
```

Is there no way to get just one unified JavaScript?

Answer (score 42):

Working offline with Google Chart API is not permitted, since it is against their [TOS](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/faq.html#offline).

Comment: So even if I manage to download all the code and use it offline I would be breaking the law?

Comment: Google is not as "open source" as they would have you believe. Some of their stuff is still proprietary.

Comment: I came to same problem, As this question is too old, just for reference, here i am adding link of google FAQs...
Answer: They don't provide Google Charts Offline..
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq
Go to this question: Can I use charts offline?

Answer (score 12):

Download this package: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4cd7zbdvv2mlg8f/gstatic.zip?dl=0

After add this code in HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gstatic/loader.js"></script>
```

This works for me.

It is to see version 44 of Google chart

Comment: Hey Alorse hope you are well.
May you please tell me how can , I use the chart offline.
May you please tell me which css or js and fonts , I need to add in my html page from the package that link you mentioned here and their order.

Comment: The only file that must include is the loader.js, as I indicated in solving the issue, do not include any CSS or anything else.

Comment: Already applied still not working.
Another thing after a long time it give version error too.

Comment: So does doing this violate Google terms and conditions or not?

Comment: RobPio, maybe I am not sure.

Comment: Just what we need, to be advising people to do things we are unsure of the legality of...

Comment: @RobPio Yes, using the Google charts offline, explicitly violates Google terms and condition. It is written in their TOS, here is a quote: "Sorry; our terms of service do not allow you to download and save or host the google.charts.load or google.visualization code. However, if you don't need the interactivity of Google Charts, you can screenshot the charts and use them as you wish.". Here is a link: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#localdownload